# CSS3 vertical-align issue

Tags: css

**So the issue I am having is that the word LOGO does not respond to vertical-align:middle and unordered list elements works just fine , how to solve this ? thanks in advance**

my HTML code:

```
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <div class="innerContainer">
                <div class="leftSide">Logo</div>
                <div class="rightSide">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Label</li>
                        <li>Label</li>
                        <li>Label</li>
                        <li class="btn">SIGN IN</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>    
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
```

my css code:

```
.innerContainer{
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 2%;
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}

header .rightSide{
   float: right;
}

header .leftSide{
 float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `display: flex` with `justify-content: space-between` to make the elements appear on the left/right, then use `align-items: center;` to center them vertically.

```css
.innerContainer {
  padding: 2%;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <div class="innerContainer">
      <div class="leftSide">Logo</div>
      <div class="rightSide">
        <ul>
          <li>Label</li>
          <li>Label</li>
          <li>Label</li>
          <li class="btn">SIGN IN</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: oh yes! :) it worked just perfectly, thank you so much, I will mark it as an answer as soon as system will let me do this ;)

Comment: @Oscar awesome no problem!